# Placing repository inside subdirectory in Databricks Repos with Terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

With Terraform I am trying to create a directory inside Repos, with a repository.

```
resource "databricks_directory" "test_directory" {
    path    = "/Repos/test123"
}

resource "databricks_repo" "test_repo" {
    url     = "https://somegiturl.com"

    path    = databricks_directory.test_directory.path
    # Other variations tried:
    #2 path    = "/Repos/test123"
    #3 path    = "${databricks_directory.test_directory.path}/"
    #4 path    = "/test123"

    branch  = "main"
}
```

The first resource successfully creates the test123 folder inside Repos.

[image: Repos Directory]

The second resource states for path option 1, 2 and 3:

Error: Invalid repo path specified

Option 4:

Error: Repos can only be created in the /Repos folder

Apparently I am missing something... How can I successfully place the repository inside the test123 folder?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to have multiple paths or just one path which is not working?

Comment: One path, the other paths were just variations in trying to achieve the same.

Comment: OK, does `path = "${databricks_directory.test_directory.path}/"` work?

Comment: No that also gives: Error: Invalid repo path specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently you need to put the repo as a folder inside the directory.

So it should be:

```
path    = "/Repos/test123/MyRepo"
```

or

```
path    = "${databricks_directory.test_directory.path}/MyRepo"
```